# Shouldn't there be a gravitational field without any mass in our 3d space?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass

Imagine there is a Neutron star Displaced a small distance from our accessible 3d slice in the direction transverse to that 3d slice. It will bend the space around it. It will also bend the space of 3rd dimension but beings in 3rd dimension will not be able to observe that mass.

This would mean we will observe gravity without mass. But we haven't observed anything like this. Could it mean there are no objects in the 4th dimension and or maybe there is no other dimension other than our own.

Comment: Related: [Shouldn't there be a gravitational field without any mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798914/shouldnt-there-be-a-gravitational-field-without-any-mass)

Comment: *Could it mean there are no objects in the 4th dimension?* Do you understand that the 4th dimension of spacetime is *time*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General relativity describes how the spacetime [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) curves in response to mass fields on this manifold. You don't have any effect of things "outside" the manifold: they are not part of the theory. There is not even a way of including them.

In your case you assume there is a bigger 4D space (plus time) where our normal space is a 3D slice, and ask what we would see if there was a mass outside our slice. Indeed, there would be curvature: this is just a bigger manifold with our normal world as a [submanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold), just like your own worldline is a 1D submanifold of spacetime. But this would hardly look like mysterious dark matter to the inhabitants of that imagined space since the theory also describes how light or other signals could move between an observer and that extra mass along geodesics. It would be "totally normal 4D space" to the inhabitants.

I think the original idea here is based on [brane theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane), where our strings/particles live on a submanifold (the brane) embedded in a higher dimensional bulk space, and gravity extends into this bulk. Note that what happens here is that it is our kind of matter and fields that are constrained to a submanifold, but there could be stuff out there affecting the fields. But while general relativity is a well-developed theory with experimental support, these brane theories are pretty theoretical and not widely accepted as a correct description of reality.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to Anders answer: Extra dimensions **can** be described by GR alone. (See e.g. Kaluza Klein modes from small compact 5th dimension). However as he said: Currently there is no experimental evidence on extra dimensions.